# java - thread.sleep() within SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, swingworker

I am just wondering if the following code is correct. I have a SwingWorker that does something, sleeps, does something else and updates GUI. Is it okay to use Thread.sleep inside SwingWorker?

```
class MySwingy extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {

        //Do Something

        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        //Do Something

    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        //Update GUI
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of Thread.sleep, use [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Comment: I tried using the TimerTask but it does not pause in between, GUI gets updated too quickly

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to, there is no technical reason why you can't do that. The thread that will block is a background thread and your UI will not block.

But may I ask why you need to sleep in a background thread? Maybe your design can be improved to remove that need?

Comment: Thank you so much. I am working on a project where I send a command to a hardware device and it replies back. There is a small time delay between send and reply.

Comment: Sawas is asking because, usually, the driver for such hardware devices will offer either blocking calls or callbacks.  These mechanisms avoid the need for sleep() calls.

Comment: Martin is right. how does it reply back? do you get a callback of some sort?

Comment: hmm I am not sure if the person that developed the driver implemented that

Comment: @jadrijan The first thing anybody implementing any driver would provide is a blocking read method. I would start by using that and throwing away the sleep.